# How can I create a lodash custom build with include option?

Tags: lodash, custom-build

I only need 2 functions from the entire library: throttle and debounce.

If I build it with one function everything works, for instance this work

`lodash include=throttle`

but if I try multiple functions comma separated, I get an error. So this :

`lodash include=throttle,debounce`

give me this :

[image]

Using windows 10 with VScode (fluent terminal or powershell, results are the same).

[Here](https://lodash.com/custom-builds) is the documentation :

[image]

Any solution?

Comment: Just to workaround that problem, try `lodash include=debounce plus=throttle`

Comment: Thanks @GabrielePetrioli it works indeed ;)

Answer (score 0):

For no obvious reasons cmd.exe work just fine. Powershell don't.

I suspect the comma being interpreted differently, not sure.

[image]